# Is there a way to use a non-bean style object as a model attribute for a spring form?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using a third party library that has objects that I want to be able to edit via a Spring (version 3.2) form.  The problem is that the object does not use the Java-beans naming convention because the properties can be dynamic in some cases.  Instead, the objects have methods like `object.getAttr("attribute_name")` and `object.setAttr("attribute_name", value)`.  It would be easy for me to write an implementation of BeanWrapper to wrap this type of object, because there are methods for querying what attributes are available, etc.

I also don't need custom editors because the properties are mostly built-in types.  All I need is a way to customize the data binding or find some other way to plug in my custom BeanWrapper so that Spring's form tag will know how find the properties on the object when binding the form values.  Seems like this should be fairly easy (that **is** why BeanWrapper is an interface, right?) but I am just not seeing it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For version 3.2 you could:

- Extends `BeanPropertyBindingResult` and override `createBeanWrapper()` method.
- Extends `ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder` and override `getInternalBindingResult()` method to return your `bindingResult` instance.
- Extends `ServletRequestDataBinderFactory` and return your `databinder` instance.
- Extends `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` and override `createDataBinder()` method.
- Register your handler adapter in dispatcher servlet context with `order < Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`.

So I think that you need to extends four framework classes to pull up a custom `BeanWrapper` into Spring MVC.

Maybe there are simpler options.

Comment: Wow!  After posting this question, I hacked around in the debugger for a while, and this is the EXACT same solution I came up with.  I'm glad I'm not the only one that is finding this difficult.  I missed setting the order on my handler adapter, however, so I was having some trouble getting it working.  I will try that and see if it works for me.

Comment: Turns out this is probably a bad idea anyway.  Getting Spring forms to work with my non-bean is just half the battle (one-third, really).  You still have JSP EL and SpEL to deal with...

Comment: Maybe you could wrap your models in a Map and access properties via wrapper[propertyName] that is already supported by BeanWrapperImpl

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing.  A little extra plumbing to push values around, but it seems to be the best solution, given how deeply rooted JavaBeans conventions are.